# calculate minutes from starting and ending time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate how many minutes a worker works from the input starting and ending time(e.g. 10:30 am to 3:30pm). Could u guys help how to calculate them? Could u check my code and correct them? I am very new in Javascript.

```
function myFunction(){
  var sTime=document.getElementById("startTime").value;
  var eTime=document.getElementById("endTime").value;
  var diff = sTime-eTime; 
  var result= diff.getMinutes();      

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=result`;
```

https://jsbin.com/bolapox/edit?html,output

Comment: You should set the <input type="time">

Comment: ok...could u solve this problem and post ur code here?

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650207/javascript-elapsed-minutes-between-two-times

Answer (score 0):

You will need to turn the users input into a usable format with `Date().parse(input)`. This returns the number of milliseconds since `1 January, 1970, 00:00:00, local time`.
You can then take the difference in milliseconds and convert them into minutes.

```
var sTime=Date().parse(document.getElementById("startTime").value);
var eTime=Date().parse(document.getElementById("endTime").value);
var diff = eTime - sTime;
var result = diff / 60000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider Moment.js, here yiou can find some examples:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/